# Add FORCE INDEX with drupal query builder

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, force-index

I am developing a website using `Drupal 7`. I was using a query with the help of function `db_query`. But now I am planning to restructure it and use the `db_select` format.

But at one portion, I am using a

```
FORCE INDEX()
```

to force the use a particular index to overcome a drawback of old `MySql` version.

**Is there any way to add this force index with the `join()` in db_select?**

Comment: use addExpression method https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x

Comment: you also convert your db_select by db_query function to write sql query https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x

Answer (score 0):

I needed custom query (with force index) for views too. I did it this way:

A] create `SelectQueryExtender` class

```
class CustomSQLQuery extends SelectQueryExtender
{

    private $customQuery;
    private $args;

    static function query($query, $args) {
        $inst = new CustomSQLQuery(db_select('node', 'n'), Database::getConnection());
        $inst->setQuery($query, $args);
        return $inst;
    }

    public function setQuery($query, $args) {
        $this->customQuery = $query;
        $this->args = $args;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this
            ->preExecute()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->connection
            ->query((string)$this->customQuery, $this->args);

    }

}
```

B] use this extender in the `hook_pre_execute(&$view)`. E.g.

```
function yourmodule_views_pre_execute(&$view) {

  if ($view->current_display == "xyz") {
     $rawQuery = "SELECT something where field = :arg1 ";
     $q = CustomSQLQuery::query($rawQuery, [
                ":arg1" => "foo"
            ]);
     $view->build_info['query'] = $q;
     $view->build_info['count_query'] = $q;
  }
}
```