# Ho to use Extender in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, extender

I would like to alter the structure of the query generated from `db_select` of Drupal. I would like to include a 'FORCE INDEX()' with `join()` function. I saw a documentation about `Drupal Extenders` [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/extenders). But I am not getting where to add the new class. There are no more examples available online. Please help

Comment: use addExpression  ?https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add FORCE INDEX with drupal query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215360/add-force-index-with-drupal-query-builder)